# Binding an extended WPF control to a dependency property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I am trying to create a custom button in WPF and want to route the existing BorderThickness property to a different property. I have simplified the code posted here but when running it it does not attempt to get or set the BorderThickness property, what am I missing please?

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyButton Width="80" Height="80"
        BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}"
        BorderBrush="#003CFF" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="20" Content="Q" FontSize="20"/>
</Grid>
```

My button class:

```
   Imports System.ComponentModel

    Public Class MyButton
        Inherits Button
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Public Shared Shadows ReadOnly BorderThicknessProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderThickness", GetType(Thickness), GetType(MyButton), New PropertyMetadata(New Thickness(10))) ', AddressOf tt)

        Public Overloads Property BorderThickness As Thickness
            Get
                Return GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Thickness)
                SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value)
                OnPropertyChanged()
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            Me.DataContext = Me
        End Sub

    #Region "INotifyPropertyChanged"
        Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(<Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName> Optional strPropertyName As String = Nothing)
            Try
                If Me.PropertyChangedEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName))
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Sub

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    #End Region

    End Class
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is to look at your output window (after launching the app of course). Do a search on that window for "BorderThickness". Chances are there's a message in there about that binding not working for some reason.

Comment: No errors are raised

Answer (score 0):

I realise I was trying to use a Thickness on a Rectangle StrokeThickness which is a Double, problem solved.